# passing arabic text and check in where cluase giving error or converted?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have to find out the existing data record from passing parameter through a stored procedure in SQL Server from using C#.

Like that

```
storedprocedurename @strclause nvarchar(200)
```

and then my complete procedure flow. Now the point of discussion comes here when I am passing the argument from c# to the procedure parameter and the parameter in Arabic like that 'أفغانستاني' the it converted to '????????' and when I check the procedure using N prefix in query analyzer it works fine. But when I pass this from code behind using c#. like that N'أفغانستاني' then query converted to complete string like that 'N''أفغانستاني' and using N'أفغانستاني' converted again 'N'?????????'.

Now the problem is how to get the exact match with N prefix and how it is possible by passing in parameter to the stored procedure. In the normal query, it works fine, but in the stored procedure, I need help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MigrateNewVisa]
    @CompanyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @VisaNos NVARCHAR(100),
    @VisaTypeIDs NVARCHAR(500), -- This is comes from c# and Arabic text but converted to ??????
    @scdate DATETIME,
    @createdby NVARCHAR(120),
    @modifyby NVARCHAR(120),
    @borderno NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @VisaTypeID  NVARCHAR(40)
    SET @VisaTypeID = (SELECT DBO.BVF_Get_VisaTypeIdByEnArName(@VisaTypeIDs)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [VisaDetails] ([ID], [CompanyID], [VisaNo], [VisaTypeID],
                               [CreatedBy], [modifyby], [borderno])
    VALUES (NEWID(), @CompanyID, @BlockVisaNos, @VisaTypeID,
            @createdby, @modifyby, @borderno)
END
```

I need data value comes from existing record

Id values not matched due to ?????? from arabic text coming in parameters, where as the values is exist

```
SET @VisaTypeID = (SELECT DBO.BVF_Get_VisaTypeIdByEnArName(@VisaTypeIDs)
```

Comment: You mentioned the C# app is specifying string literals but you should be using parameterized queries instead. Add the C# code to your question.

Comment: What is `@strclause`? Why only 1 parameter when your stored proc has 7? Are you not using parameters in your c# SqlCommand?

Comment: Where are you observing the Question Marks?  Sometimes the screen will display `??????` while the underlying value is correct.  This can happen when the thing responsible for displaying the text on the screen is not compatible with multi-byte character sets.  Many times a display anomaly does not affect the data transfer.